# Hide or move seleted Cell and load a new custom Cell in that indexPath.row in UItableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` call `myTableView` with two custom `UITableViewCell` call `TableViewCell` & `ExTableViewCell`. What I want is, when user tap on a cell, the existing cell `TableViewCell` will hide/move and `ExTableViewCell` is loaded in that `indexpath.row` and when tap on that `indexpath.row` again it hide `ExTableViewCell` and bring back the old `TableViewCell` in that position.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", nil];
    selectedIndex = -1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        return 230;
    }
    else
    {
        return 40;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell *Cell = (TableViewCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!Cell)
    {
        Cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Cell.myLabel.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellEx";
        ExTableViewCell *Cell = (ExTableViewCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!Cell)
        {
            Cell = [[ExTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        Cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        Cell.exLabel.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        // Do close cell stuff
        //Cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return Cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Expand row when user taps row
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        selectedIndex = -1;
        [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:  UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        return;
    }

    // When user taps different row
    if (selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        NSIndexPath *prevPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    // When user taps new row with none expanded
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

But for some reason in the `ExTableViewCell` `label` is not showing any text. And the `ExTableViewCell` is still top of it. How can I achieve this?

A lot a thanks for advance. Have a good day. :)

This is the out put:

[image]

My problem:

[image]

Comment: I think this problem occur due to reusing your cell.You took static cell identifier so that when ever you reload table or cell at that time the memory allocated to that cell i.e. TableViewCell is not assign to different cell. So every time your cell is expand but not configure as your custom cell.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to 'hide' the old cell in order to show the new one, you just reload the proper content at the desired index path. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.selectedPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        //configure the extended cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellEx" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ...
    } else {
        //configure the default cell
    }
}
```

And here is how to handle the selected/deselected state:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSIndexPath *oldPath = [self.selectedPath copy];
    self.selectedPath = indexPath;
    NSArray *paths = @[indexPath];
    if (oldPath && ![oldPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        paths = [paths arrayByAddingObject:oldPath];
    } else if ([oldPath isEqual:indexPath]){
        self.selectedPath = nil;
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I use `selectedPath` just like you which is a `NSIndexPath` and change my `didSeectRow` but it is loading different data, when I tap on some index.
It would be really appreciable if you give me some link of tutorial or something.